# Inserting a dict inside a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to inster a dictionnaire inside a dictionnaire in python, but i have this problem : unhashable type: 'dict'
the problem is that i'm pretty new in Python and couldn't understand the problem of others persons.

Here's my code and what I would like to do :

```
iditem = {"name" : "item1", "prix" : "1000", "trades" : "10000"}
iditem2 = {"name" : "item2", "prix" : "2000", "trades" : "20000"}
iditem3 = {"name" : "item3", "prix" : "5000", "trades" : "50000"}

encyclo = {iditem,iditem2,iditem3}

print(encyclo[iditem["name"]])
```

I just would like to be able to have a dictionnaire inside a dictionnaire and to find it easily.
Anyway thank you for your time !

Comment: `{iditem,iditem2,iditem3}` tries to create a *set* of dictionaries, but you cannot because dictionaries are unhashable. What exactly are you trying to create? Perhaps something like `encyclo = {d['name']: d for d in [iditem, iditem2, iditem3]}`? It is unclear

Comment: What do you want the *keys* of `encyclo` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a simple fix. Every dictionary needs a key AND value. You can give your `encyclo` keys just like the above dictionaries.

To access nested properties in a dictionary, you use brackets for the first dictionary, close them, and then re-open them to access nested properties.

```py
iditem = {"name" : "item1", "prix" : "1000", "trades" : "10000"}
iditem2 = {"name" : "item2", "prix" : "2000", "trades" : "20000"}
iditem3 = {"name" : "item3", "prix" : "5000", "trades" : "50000"}

#            key:    value
#            ↓↓       ↓↓
encyclo = {"item1": iditem, "item2": iditem2, "item3": iditem3}

#             iditem    name
#               ↓↓↓      ↓↓
print(encyclo["item1"]["name"])
```